# Use @predestroy method to execute pending instructions at session end?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, session-scope

Is it safe to store pending executions list in context of a user's actions within a web app in a session scoped bean & then reliably execute those actions at the end of session through `@Predestroy` annotated method(*i mean, safety in context of `@predestroy` method not getting called & thus action not being executed under some circumstances or so* !? ).

Comment: that instantaneous bad title was a result of a typo error while I pressed submit button due to which my title got erased..

Comment: @Juan: look at the question tags.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're concretely asking. But it would make completely sense to me that they won't be exeucted when the server got crashed or killed. Is that what you need to know? Or is that illogical? Or have you observed entirely different behaviour? *By the way, why are you favoriting this question? Even without the favorite you would as being the asker by default already be notified of any new activity.*

Comment: I don't mind if occasionally/rarely/once upon a time, the action was not executed but  can't tolerate usually.

Comment: @BalusC Tags were added because I asked the question.

Comment: upvoted back to zero because it's a fair question about implementing an interesting aspect and the poster added the tags as requested

Comment: Downvoted back because the question does not make any sense. It's like asking others to hold your hands tight. Stack Overflow is more a place where *real problems* are to be asked and answered. The OP does not seem to have any concrete real problem at all, just some ungrounded uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at moving your logic to a HttpSessionListener implementation (it's an interface).  you would trigger on sessionDestroyed events (via implementing that method in your concrete implementation).

it's pretty easy, to use and a great spot to handle this kind of thing (i implemented one in a current product as a JMX bean to handle controlling sessions at runtime).

TIA

Comment: A `@Predestroy` annotated method of a `@SessionScoped` managed bean is behind the JSF scenes already invoked by `HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed()`. So I completely fail to see how it's useful and "more safe" to replace that with a homegrown implementation.

Comment: didnt offer it as "more safe", just making it semantically targeted.  yes there is more than one way to skin this cat, but since he's specifically interested triggering some behavior/aspect during session destroy, it might make more sense to put the logic in a bean that is targeted for that behavior.  if his callback needs other beans/resources that are unnecessary during "normal operation", having them injected just so they're available at session destroy could be constituted a pollution of the bean.  again, without showing code, it would have to be weighed in the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely safe to store the pending executions or DB commits in the @preDestroy method. In this state there the Managed bean will not be destroyed. So the state of the managed bean will be same as it is a normal method call inside the bean. Please refer below documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmgkd.html#gmghg

"To Prepare for the Destruction of a Managed Bean Using the @PreDestroy Annotation
Preparing for the destruction of a managed bean specifies the lifecycle call back method that signals that an application component is about to be destroyed by the container.

In the managed bean class or any of its superclasses, prepare for the destruction of the managed bean.
In this method, perform any cleanup that is required before the bean is destroyed, such as releasing a resource that the bean has been holding.

Annotate the declaration of the method with the javax.annotation.PreDestroy annotation.
CDI calls this method before starting to destroy the bean."